# message type for wheel angular velocity and direction

Tags: ros, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi everyone

I want to publish wheel angular velocity and its rotation direction message from my base_controller package to arduino. Now i dont know which message type is appropriate to use for this work in common_msgs stack. Because i need to have 2 numbers which contain a number for angular velocity and a number which is 0 or 1 to demonstrate direction of my motor.

Is Twist a good case? Does someone have an idea? Thanks:))

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199521/message-type-for-wheel-angular-velocity-and-direction/) by [mohammad](https://answers.ros.org/users/19955/mohammad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2014-12-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Make a [Custom Message](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/DefiningCustomMessages) with float and bool as members.

---

Originally posted by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) with karma: 3034 on 2014-12-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0